# "Cannot send headers; headers already sent in"

Tags: zend-framework, checkout

I have a problem with my payment plugin. When I go to checkout and choose payment method (Debit Card) and when I click Pay I receive an error:

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1109899841387

When I go to error log I have info:

a:5:{i:0;s:152:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/designed4gam/ftp/main/main/app/code/community/PayU/Account/controllers/PaymentController.php, line 91";i:1;s:1791:"#0 /home/designed4gam/ftp/main/main/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)

## 1 /home/designed4gam/ftp/main/main/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(106): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('https://www.des...', 302)

## 2 /home/designed4gam/ftp/main/main/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(712): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('https://www.des...')

## 3 /home/designed4gam/ftp/main/main/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(690): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->setRedirectWithCookieCheck('checkout/onepag...', Array)

## 4 /home/designed4gam/ftp/main/main/app/code/community/PayU/Account/controllers/PaymentController.php(92): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->_redirect('checkout/onepag...', Array)

## 5 /home/designed4gam/ftp/main/main/app/code/community/PayU/Account/controllers/PaymentController.php(56): PayU_Account_PaymentController->_redirectAction('failure')

## 6 /home/designed4gam/ftp/main/main/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): PayU_Account_PaymentController->newAction()

## 7 /home/designed4gam/ftp/main/main/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('new')

## 8 /home/designed4gam/ftp/main/main/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

## 9 /home/designed4gam/ftp/main/main/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

## 10 /home/designed4gam/ftp/main/main/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

## 11 /home/designed4gam/ftp/main/main/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')

## 12 {main}";s:3:"url";s:28:"/index.php/payu/payment/new/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}

I have no idea what to do... anyone could help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And this is tagged Java why?

Comment: just edited. sorry

Comment: @NikodemDyzma You see that line: `PaymentController.php, line 91`? Well, on that line is a method `_redirect`, in which a response header is set. E.g. the programmer instructs with it the server to include the line `Location: https://www.des...` into his response to the browser. When the browser sees the line, then it redirects to `https://www.des...`. The problem is, that before the call of the method on line 91 nothing must be "printed". So, before it, you are not allowed to use any function (`echo`, `var_dump`, etc) that outputs something (on screen).

Comment: @NikodemDyzma Not even blank spaces are allowed to exist before that method. So, for example, if you have something like " <?php" (notice the space) before that method, you will receive the error.

Comment: aendeerei thank you very much. that solved my problem. I removed (echo) and now work perfect. thanks again!

Comment: @NikodemDyzma You are very welcome. [Here](http://www.nicholassolutions.com/tutorials/php/headers.html) and [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) are some easy to understand materials for learning about the headers. Which are very important in HTTP request-response cycle. Good luck. P.S: Please write an answer and mark it as accepted, so that other users can benefit from it too.

Answer (score 0):

@NikodemDyzma You see that line: PaymentController.php, line 91? Well, on that line is a method _redirect, in which a response header is set. E.g. the programmer instructs with it the server to include the line Location: https://www.des... into his response to the browser. When the browser sees the line, then it redirects to https://www.des.... The problem is, that before the call of the method on line 91 nothing must be "printed". So, before it, you are not allowed to use any function (echo, var_dump, etc) that outputs something (on screen). – aendeerei